# BASH getopts problem

Tags: bash

Does anyone know why it doesnt do anything?

```
moznostm=
moznostl=
moznosta=
moznostb=
while getopts ":m:l:b:a:h:" OPTION
do
case $OPTION in
m)
moznostm=$OPTARG
echo "bol zadany argument $moznost"
;;
l)
moznostl=$OPTARG
echo bol zadany argument $OPTARG
;;
b)
moznostb=$OPTARG
echo bol zadany argument $OPTARG
;;
a)
moznosta=$OPTARG
echo bol zadany argument $OPTARG
;;
h)
echo prazny
;;
esac
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few modifications.

1) Set your shebang!  `#!/bin/bash`  if you write bash

2) Reset if    getopts was used previously

3) You forgot an `m` at  `$moznost`.

4) Don't use uppercase for normal variable names.

5) Use more quotes. Double quotes `" "` when expanding variables.
6) Use `shift`.

7) You don't have to define / initialize variables like you are doing here `moznostm=` .

```
#!/bin/bash

OPTIND=1

    moznostm=
    moznostl=
    moznosta=
    moznostb=
    while getopts "mlbah:" opt
    do
    case "$opt" in
    m)
    moznostm=$OPTARG
    echo "bol zadany argument $moznostm"
    ;;
    l)
    moznostl=$OPTARG
    echo "bol zadany argument $OPTARG"
    ;;
    b)
    moznostb=$OPTARG
    echo "bol zadany argument $OPTARG"
    ;;
    a)
    moznosta=$OPTARG
    echo "bol zadany argument $OPTARG"
    ;;
    h)
    echo "prazny"
    ;;
    esac
    done
shift "$((OPTIND-1))"
```

Execute the script:

```
chmod +x scriptname && ./scripname -m
```

Comment: What do you mean by point "7"? Certainly you don't want to use a variable uninitialised (especially when considering that shells inherit variables from the environment).

Comment: By point 7, I mean that `moznostm=` seems to be pointless. If it was a variable holding an integer, then there are situations a variable should be initialized as `0` so you could start counting or do other arithmetic calculations. In the setting as it is now, I don't see how `moznostm=` is going to help.

Comment: `moznostm=` would set the default value of `$moznostm` to the empty string as opposed to what value it got from the environment. You'd need `m:` in the option specification btw if you're going to use `$OPTARG`.

Comment: Well I'm not really sure if I understand the purpose though. Feel free to improve the answer and provide some examples which demonstrates the caveats

Comment: A few additional remarks on the proposed solution. ad 1) The code snippet would also work with `ksh`. ad 5) Some variable expansion contexts don't require quoting; as the assignment was left unquoted, also the `case` argument (or the `shift` argument) don't require quoting. ad 6) To clarify; `shift` is only necessary if you have further arguments to be processed.

Comment: Well when it comes to quoting, you should always quote in bash unless you really really know what you are doing:  "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and _every_ expansion: "$var", "$(command "$var")",  "${array[@]}", "a & b". Use 'single quotes' for code or literal $'s: 'Costs $5 US', ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes , http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: @val0x00ff; so you imply that you don't know what you are doing? (Since you quote some items unnecessarily, while you omit other unnecessary quotes deliberately.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your script with an option and an option-argument. For example:

```
bash yourscript -l argumentfor_l
```

Note also that `moznost` is printed but never defined.